# Gradient vs Directional Derivative Visually

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis, inner-products, slope

[Gradient vs Directional Derivative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLuIv.png)

As you can see in the image I have shown Gradient of hill by blue vector. Vector red indicates direction of max slope.
I have understood the gradient.

The problem I have is with directional derivative.

I have written equation for directional derivative.

Now, at (theta) = 0, directional derivative = gradient.

But if we increase theta, what happens then?

Blue vector shrinks? (reduction in magnitude?)
(I think No.)

Or it it start pointing upward? (shown by red vector)

If yes! then does it have to be in same black colored vertical plane?

What is directional derivative visually? does it represent same vector that gradient does?

Please clarify. I tried lots of videos, it confused me more.

Comment: There are several problems with your image. The directional derivative in any direction is a scalar, but the gradient is a vector. They cannot be equal.

Comment: To mention a few more problems: You're missing absolute value sign around $\nabla f$ in the expression $|\nabla f| \cos\theta$. And the angle $\theta$ is *really* not the angle you have drawn in the picture, it's the angle between $\nabla f$ and $\vec{v}$, which are vectors that should be drawn in the *plane*, not in space. In your picture, $\vec{v}$ isn't even present.

Comment: In horizontal plane?

Comment: I am not concerned much about representation right now. If the gradient represents max steep ascent, then, I wanna know what directional derivative does? In simple words? and how they are related?

Comment: Thanks for help! I understood concept from here in case case anyone else also struggling.

Comment: https://mathinsight.org/directional_derivative_gradient_introduction